# My username, password and i.p. were public. Was I hacked?

Tags: 18.04, security, hacking

Through a series of poor choices, the username, root password, and i.p. address to my Ubuntu machine were pushed to a public repository.

Now, I've changed my password and purged the repo of the information *but*, my username and password were public for about two days before I noticed. What checks can I make to ensure that my machine wasn't compromised?

Edit:
It seems like the best course of action will be to do a system restore. I need to keep this machine running for the next two weeks though. Any suggestions for mitigating damage in the meantime?

Comment: Were you behind a firewall? *Could* someone from outside have connected to your machine via ssh?

Comment: Yes, I'm behind a firewall. I have never enabled ssh access, and `auth.log` doesn't show any ssh access in the last 3 days.

Comment: You can try and use the `debsums` command to verify some of your current system. See `man debsums` for help.

Comment: Thanks for the `debsums` tip. Tried that, and it found no errors, but a lot of the locale files came up `REPLACED`. Not exactly sure what that means, but not suspicious as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take it down, reinstall from scratch, reinstall apps, reconfigure them, restore your data from a date before the keys to the kingdom were given away.

You can use any number of methods to look for script kiddies and other misinformed misbehaviour, but if you were rooted well, you won't know it.

FYI, your IP address is issued by your Internet Service Provider. Unless you paid extra for a static IP address, it is almost certainly assigned dynamically, and almost certainly changed by the ISP when your interface device (Cable or DSL 'modem') is reset.

Comment: So it seems like there are some ways to check whether I've been rooted, but if they did a good job, I'll never know it, correct?

Comment: Some folks might think this is going too far...but I completely agree with this answer. If some joker knew your password in order to post it online, then you have a bigger security problem than a mere password change. Yes, you will lose a lot of data if you don't keep backups -- that's the expensive price of not keeping backups.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. You should change the machine's password immediately. Check if you have any missing files by comparing it to your backups. If you have missing files or additional files that you didn't create. It's an obvious sign of being compermised.